# Problem with Android list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am having a problem in Android, when i set the adapter the list view is not updating. 
This i use to delete one note from the database:

```
listaNotas.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, final long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
            dialogo.setTitle("Confirmação");
            dialogo.setMessage("Deseja mesmo deletar a nota?");
            dialogo.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    db.delete("Notas", "_id=?", (new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}));
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Nota deletada com sucesso!", 5).show();
                    atualizaNota();
                    return;
                }
            });
            dialogo.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
            dialogo.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and this is the updates of the adapter:

```
public void atualizaNota() {
    Cursor c = db.query("Notas", (new String[]{"_id", "Nota"}), "fgCompromisso=?", (new String[]{"0"}), null, null, "_id DESC");
    if (c.getCount()==0)
        return;
    String[] from = {"Nota"};
    int[] to = {R.id.edDescNota};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main.this, R.layout.layoutlistanota, c, from, to);
    listaNotas.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Is there any problem within the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `requery()` to your cursor in order changes to be visible. Just declare the cursor as instance field and call it after deleting like:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    db.delete("Notas", "_id=?", (new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}));
    c.requery(); // This is all you need
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Nota deletada com sucesso!", 5).show();
    atualizaNota();
    return;
}
```

Also, don't forget to close it `onPause()` (if you did not done it already)

Comment: Actually i was pretty dumb, when i had only one note and deleted it, it felt on:

Comment: if (c.getCount()==0)
        return;
Then just din't update the adapter.... my dumbness is awsome. ;D
But your answer helped a lot! =D